# Selecting rows and colums of a table using jquery and update its content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML table followed by a simple form which accepts the table row and column like below

```
 <table border="1" style="width:100%">
   <tr>
     <td>Row 1 Col1</td>
     <td>Row 1 Col2</td>
     <td>Row 1 Col3</td>
     <td>Row 1 Col4</td>
     <td>Row 1 Col5</td>
     <td>Row 1 Col6</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Row 2 Col1</td>
     <td>Row 2 Col2</td>
     <td>Row 2 Col3</td>
     <td>Row 2 Col4</td>
     <td>Row 2 Col5</td>
     <td>Row 2 Col6</td>
   </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>Row 3 Col1</td>
     <td>Row 3 Col2</td>
     <td>Row 3 Col3</td>
     <td>Row 3 Col4</td>
     <td>Row 3 Col5</td>
     <td>Row 3 Col6</td>
   </tr>   
 </table> 
 <form>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Row" value="row"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Column" value="column"/>
      <button id="submitButton" type="submit"> Submit </button>
 </form>
```

Table row and column can vary and can have n number of rows and columns. What i would like to do is based on the user input (selecting rows and column and submitting it) i want to update the content of the user selected row and column to say "Hello". if user selects a column, row combination which is not available alert an error message. How could i do this in jquery.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#submitButton').click(
 function(){
   var numrow = $('#numrow').val();
   var numcol = $('#numcol').val();
   var enttotal = numrow * numcol;
   var lenrow = $('.dataupdate tr').length;
   var lencol = $('.dataupdate tr:first-child td').length;
   var tcol  = $('.dataupdate tr td').length;
 if(numrow <= lenrow &&  numcol <= lencol && enttotal <= tcol){ 
   $('.dataupdate tr:nth-child('+numrow+') td:nth-child('+numcol+')').html('Hello')
     }
  else { alert('there is no such column in this table'); }
  });
```

this is working fiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/6vj92vcp/

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this,

```
$("#submitButton").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var r = parseInt($("#row").val()) - 1;
    var c = parseInt($("#column").val()) - 1;
    $("table").find("tr").eq(r).find("td").eq(c).text("hello");

});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/n32bxhzb/2/)

It is an undex based approach. First you need to find the nth row using the `.eq()` selector. Since the index is starting from 0, you need to decrement the actual value by 1.

You can use `.find()` method to get all the child elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submitButton").click(function(){       
        var row       = parseInt($("#rows").val())-1;
        var col       = parseInt($("#cows").val())-1;
        var greeting = "hello";

        if(isNaN(row)|| isNaN(col)) {
             alert('Please enter a valid row and column number');
             return false;
        }

        var x = $("table").find("tr").eq(row).find("td").eq(col);
        if(x.length==0)
           alert('Such a row and column not found ');   
        else if(x.text()==greeting)
           alert("Already selected "); 
        else 
           x.text(greeting);
        return false;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tintucraju/fm0sL4s9/